# React Native - integration not send data

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile, axios, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to login via mobile, but the data is not sent.
On the web it works normally.
In Postman it works normally.

The React Native returns the error message: "response": "{"message":"email must be an email, password must be a string"}";

Integration code with Axios:

```
export const SignInBody = () => {
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(true);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const handleLogin = () => {
    axios
      .post(`${PROTOCOL}${REACT_APP_BACK_URL}/login`, {
        email: login,
        password: password,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('userId', response.data.data.id)?.toString();
        navigation.navigate('Root', { screen: 'one' });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response);
        errorAlert({
          title: 'Atenção',
          msg: 'Email ou senha incorretos',
          btn: 'Ok',
        });
      });
  };
```

When i try to login via mobile, the full error message:

```
Object {
  "config": Object {
    "adapter": [Function xhrAdapter],
    "data": "{}",
    "env": Object {
      "FormData": null,
    },
    "headers": Object {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, /",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "method": "post",
    "timeout": 0,
    "transformRequest": Array [
      [Function transformRequest],
    ],
    "transformResponse": Array [
      [Function transformResponse],
    ],
    "transitional": Object {
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
    },
    "url": "https://mybackurl",
    "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
  },
  "data": Object {
    "message": "email must be an email, password must be a string",
  },
  "headers": Object {
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "63",
    "content-security-policy": "default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "date": "Fri, 15 Jul 2022 03:59:44 GMT",
    "etag": "W/\"3f-ALOE7r8MX9pcEta7jauOf258lOM\"",
    "expect-ct": "max-age=0",
    "referrer-policy": "no-referrer",
    "server": "Cowboy",
    "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "via": "1.1 vegur",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "x-dns-prefetch-control": "off",
    "x-download-options": "noopen",
    "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies": "none",
    "x-xss-protection": "0",
  },
  "request": XMLHttpRequest {
    "DONE": 4,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
    "LOADING": 3,
    "OPENED": 1,
    "UNSENT": 0,
    "_aborted": false,
    "_cachedResponse": undefined,
    "_hasError": false,
    "_headers": Object {
      "accept": "application/json, text/plain, /",
      "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    "_incrementalEvents": false,
    "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": Object {
      "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "content-length": "63",
      "content-security-policy": "default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "date": "Fri, 15 Jul 2022 03:59:44 GMT",
      "etag": "W/\"3f-ALOE7r8MX9pcEta7jauOf258lOM\"",
      "expect-ct": "max-age=0",
      "referrer-policy": "no-referrer",
      "server": "Cowboy",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains",
      "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
      "via": "1.1 vegur",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "x-dns-prefetch-control": "off",
      "x-download-options": "noopen",
      "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies": "none",
      "x-xss-protection": "0",
    },
    "_method": "POST",
    "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://mybackurl",
    "_performanceLogger": PerformanceLogger {
      "_closed": false,
      "_extras": Object {},
      "_pointExtras": Object {},
      "_points": Object {
        "initializeCore_end": 1657857539044,
        "initializeCore_start": 1657857538868,
      },
      "_timespans": Object {
        "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://192.168.15.7:19000/logs": Object {
          "endExtras": undefined,
          "endTime": 1657857540601,
          "startExtras": undefined,
          "startTime": 1657857540513,
          "totalTime": 88,
        },
        "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://192.168.15.7:19000/symbolicate": Object {
          "endExtras": undefined,
          "endTime": 1657857540548,
          "startExtras": undefined,
          "startTime": 1657857540120,
          "totalTime": 428,
        },
        "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://mybackurl": Object {
          "endExtras": undefined,
          "endTime": 1657857583334,
          "startExtras": undefined,
          "startTime": 1657857558247,
          "totalTime": 25087,
        },
      },
    },
    "_requestId": null,
    "_response": "{\"message\":\"email must be an email, password must be a string\"}",
    "_responseType": "",
    "_sent": true,
    "_subscriptions": Array [],
    "_timedOut": false,
    "_trackingName": "unknown",
    "_url": "MYBACKURL",
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseHeaders": Object {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "63",
      "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Date": "Fri, 15 Jul 2022 03:59:44 GMT",
      "Etag": "W/\"3f-ALOE7r8MX9pcEta7jauOf258lOM\"",
      "Expect-Ct": "max-age=0",
      "Referrer-Policy": "no-referrer",
      "Server": "Cowboy",
      "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains",
      "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
      "Via": "1.1 vegur",
      "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
      "X-Dns-Prefetch-Control": "off",
      "X-Download-Options": "noopen",
      "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
      "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies": "none",
      "X-Xss-Protection": "0",
    },
    "responseURL": "MYBACKURL",
    "status": 400,
    "timeout": 0,
    "upload": XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {},
    "withCredentials": true,
  },
  "status": 400,
  "statusText": undefined,
```

for security, i hide the url on the code;

Answer (score 0):

That's something looks like mismatch data format while requesting from axios client. Try to pass your credentials as a form data with appropriate headers on request, specify the content-type in header, on request. For Example:

```
   let data = {
             email: login,
             password: password,           
            }

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append(JSON.stringify(data));
   axios({
   url    : "endpoint",
   method : 'POST',
   data   : formData,
   headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
                console.log("response :", response);
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("error");
       })
```